# Why does this thread only run once?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a server running on a separate thread, and for some reason, it only runs when it receives packets! Why is it doing this? Shouldn't it be running continuously?

```
public void run() {
    while (running) {
        System.out.println(true);
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
        try {
            this.socket.receive(packet);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        parsePacket(packet.getData(), packet.getAddress(), packet.getPort());
    }
}
```

And I start it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    GameServer server = new GameServer();
    server.start();
}
```

The class extends Thread.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't run? What should it do when there are no packets?

Comment: Where is `running` declared and is the value changing?

Comment: @Ingo Shouldn't it be constantly running? Or do I not know how threads work at all...

Comment: @SatishBejgum running is always true, I know that.

Comment: maybe this.socket.receive(packet) is waiting for packet and stopping thread execution?

Comment: Without knowing the socket interface, I'm guessing the receive method blocks until it actually receives something. Check the interface description for that. Also, I hope your "running" variable is defined as volatile.

Comment: Does it really stop running or does it just suspend? I'm not familiar with sockets but I guess `this.socket.receive(packet);` is blocking until it receives a package or gets a timeout.

Comment: @opiop65 Tell us what you think the thread should do when there is no packet. Also, tell us what you mean exactly by "not running"? How do you notice it is not running?

Comment: @Ingo I don't know what it should do, that's why I asked? And it just stops running I.E. nothing happens. I print out a statement inside the loop, and it only prints when a packet is received.

Comment: Debugging should help you better.

Comment: @SatishBejgum I have debugged! That's why I'm here, I can't figure it out. This community should be about helping people, not telling them to do generic things like debugging.

Comment: I took a look at the DatagramSocket interface, the receive method blocks until it actually receives something.

Comment: You really do need to read the API documentation before taking your problem to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`socket.receive` is a blocking method. So the code is waiting on receive untill you receive any data.

Comment: Finally, a straight forward answer! Thank you!

Comment: +1 in other words a debugger would have shown you this in a couple of seconds.

Answer (score 3):

From [here](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#receive%28java.net.DatagramPacket%29)

```
public void receive(DatagramPacket p)
             throws IOException
```

> Receives a datagram packet from this socket. When this method returns,
>   the DatagramPacket's buffer is filled with the data received. The
>   datagram packet also contains the sender's IP address, and the port
>   number on the sender's machine.
>
> This method blocks until a datagram is received. The length field of
>   the datagram packet object contains the length of the received
>   message. If the message is longer than the packet's length, the
>   message is truncated.

It clearly says that method blocks and wait for Datagram.

Answer (score 3):

Your Thread is running correctly. The method [`DatagramSocket.receive(DatagramPacket)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#receive%28java.net.DatagramPacket%29)  blocks until a packet is received.

The default behaviour is to block infinitely until a packet is received. You can specfiy a timeout using [`DatagramSocket.setSoTimeout(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#setSoTimeout%28int%29), if you want to periodically log whether a packet is received or not, or to check if your Thread is still running.